# Pass datepicker's date parameter to get resources in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

My current calendar looks like this :

[full-calendar design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mReEP.png)

What I'm trying to do is change calendar date when I click a date in datepicker ( which is already done using .fullCalendar('gotoDate',date ) ) , the thing is , to get the resources and events I need to re-send the query to the server with the new value of 'date'  , otherwise the calendar won't reload the data.

Here's the url I'm using to get the resources :

```
resources: 
            {

                url: '/general?handler=AllResources', 
                data: function () { 
                    return {
                        // must return the new date to display in calendar
                    };

                }
            }
```

'AllResources' method only get a few records depending on the date specificied 
  as parameter.

BTW : I'm rendering fullCalendar in document.ready , then I have the following function to give my datepicker the 'changeDate' functionality :

```
$('.fc-center h2').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                language: "es",
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                todayHighlight: true

            }).on("changeDate", function (e) {


                var date = moment(e.date);

                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);




            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if i unserstand your problem.

So if you change the date, the resources don't get updated?
Have a look at [refetchResourcesOnNavigate](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/refetchResourcesOnNavigate)

[edit]
Try this:

```
$('.fc-center h2').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                language: "es",
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                todayHighlight: true

            }).change(function (e) {
             var mydate =moment($(this).val(),'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

       $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', mydate);

});
```

And then when initializing the calender set 'refetchResourcesOnNavigate: true' to make sure whenever the calendar changes the resources get loaded again

Comment: Yes, when the fullCalendar is already rendered I haven't selected a datepicker's date yet , so obviously it doesn't know what parameter ( date ) send in the URL .

Comment: so if you select a date in the datepicker, your calendar updates to the correct date but the resources don't change?

Comment: i edited my reply. there was also a problem with the date format

Comment: adding refetchResourcesOnNavigate:true did the thing , thanks man . However , the other views doesn't show the events ( month , week , 2 day views )  , I wrote a new question about it , I'd appreciate if you could check it out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766583/show-events-in-all-the-views-of-fullcalendar

Comment: The link to your other question won't load. Let me know if you still need help with that

Comment: Unfortunately your other question is on hold. I think it can answer it. Please edit the question